# How do I connect to a localhost service from a hyper-v VM?

Tags: wcf, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I have a WCF service running on "http://localhost:12345/ServiceName". I also have a VM running under hyper-v in Windows 8 public beta. Is there any way that I can connect to this service from the VM? I cant seem to set up a bridged network connection in the hyper-v manager. An alternative would be for the WCF service to bind to the Win8 machine name or IP, but I don't know how I would find out what that endpoint is from the VM side. The WCF service can be changed in any way needed...

Any help would be much appreciated!

Many thanks,
Jon

Comment: I asked a related (I think) comment on [server fault](http://serverfault.com/questions/430253/connecting-to-iis-on-hyper-v-windows-8-host-from-xp-virtual-machine), but no answers. Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this will work with a Windows VM, but I managed to open host's URL from inside an Ubuntu VM:

1. On Host disable the Firewall or add a rule to allow connections to the respective port (12345 in your case).
2. On VM edit `/etc/hosts`, replace `127.0.0.1  localhost` with `IP_OF_HOST localhost`.

Now http://localhost:12345/ServiceName should open from inside the VM.

Answer (score -1):

you can create Virtual Switch in Hyper-V(Virtual Switch Manager) Then you can connect it to your VM(right click on VM ->setting -> create Legaci network adapter -> connect abouve virtual switch to it). after that you should install intigration to Hyper-V for your OS in VM. then you can connect to your virtual switch in your VM. after that you can access internet as well. you your host machine has it. type your host machine's IP address in web browser and you can access any service in host machine

You also need to run as admin on the host machine command shell `netsh http add urlacl url=http://*:12345/ user=Everyone` where 12345 is the port number of your service.

Comment: I tried the above in Hyper-V for Win8 Pro, using both the IE7-Vista and IE8-WIn7 VMs from http://modern.ie but was unable to access localhost.

Comment: This might help someone else: http://blog.somewhatabstract.com/2014/11/24/debugging-iis-express-website-from-a-hyperv-virtual-machine/

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve the problem. And I don't think that there's any way to do so since loopback interface exists on every VM and you wouldn't want to redirect localhost.